# Time evolution of a classical system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, time-evolution

For a harmonic oscillator the Liouville operator is given by $$L = p \partial_q- q \partial_p.$$ Now I have a phase space distribution $f(t,q,p)$ for which it holds (in general) $$f(t+\tau,q,p)= T\exp(\int_t^{t+\tau}L(s)ds) f(t,q,p)$$ with a time ordering operator $T$ because of $\partial_tf=Lf$. Now on the harmonic oscillator an additional force $a \sin(t)$ is exerted. The Liouville operator then turns to $$L(s) = p \partial_q- (q+f \sin(s)) \partial_p.$$

Now the phase space distribution obeyes: $$f(t+\tau,q,p)= T\exp((p \partial_q- q \partial_p) \tau-\int_t^{t+\tau}f \sin(s) \partial_pds) f(t,q,p).$$

Can above Expression be simplified? How this Expression can be simplified (it is better to Show also detailed calculation steps)? I think the [Magnus Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion) would be useful. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!